# Clean URL htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, clean-urls

I want to make my website links to be changed from that

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?a=page&b=about
```

to that

```
http://www.egysocial.tk/about
```

and i want to redirect my old URL to the new one.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?a=page&b=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=page&b=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Error 404 Not found !! :/

Comment: @ZuckerbergMFSN Sorry, the `(,*)` should have been a period: `(.*)`

Comment: Can i ask another question ? i have a social network, and i want the users profiles link to be changed from that "http://www.egysocial.tk/index.php?a=profile&u=skdlwasd541s6ad41"

to that

http://www.egysocial.tk/user-name
and also redirect the old URL to the new one
Thanks :D